# How to make Dropdown menu items overlay other blocks

Tags: css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdown, z-index

I've this breadcrumb section that contains a dropdown menu, but the list is shown behind other block. I know this issue is common and tried to play with the number of z-index but nothing worked.

Here is the code:

```
           <div class="breadcrumb-wrap ">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item dropdown show">
                        1nd menu
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down color-info"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Sub1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Sub2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Sub3</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item dropdown show">
                        2nd menu
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down color-info"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Sub1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Sub2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

the second block:

```
<section class="s-pt-xl-60 s-pt-lg-60 s-pt-md-60 s-pt-60 s-pb-xl-280 s-pb-lg-250 s-pb-md-90 s-pb-60">
    <div class="container">
        //some code
    </div>
</section>
```

and for the dropdown, it has the default css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.9rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    font-size: inherit;
    right: auto;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1004;
}
```

what am I missing in this code?

Answer (score 1):

To make `z-index` works you must also set the `position` and must NOT be static.

So, add also the `position` on your class and will bring it in front.